# PHP json_encode(); exclude array

Tags: php

In my array, I have very long variables that are used as a security token to prevent people who don't have authority to the PHP server out.
However, I want to be able to log the data to review for bad actions if the variables passed the security wall, but I can't seem to find a way to exclude some variables to prevent getting my log file too big and rotating frequently.

```
logissue("User ".$authname." is now preforming ".json_encode($data));
```

returns and logs this huge hunk of data..

```
66.***.***.**  2015/08/03 06:28:52  User Nickoplier is now preforming {"Validate":"n@xrbycrzF6*au8c8.....","Action":"message","auth":":ZzWh[a....","Parameter1":"2933***","Parameter2":"hello :D","Parameter3":"just a test"}
```

Is it possible to exclude logging 'Validate' and 'auth'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply add:

```
unset($data['Validate'], $data['auth']);
```

Before the line converting the array into JSON. You can replicate this with as many array keys as you'd like. You can even exclude sub-keys of child arrays: `unset($data['stuff']['more-stuff']['field'])`

This will delete that key, so a better way would be to wrap the whole component inside a function and pass `$data` in.

Comment: Note: ``unset`` deletes that entry so be sure that you don't need them later